# What does the phrase "His mouth worked when he thought" mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms

“Jody was only a little boy, ten years old, with hair like dusty yellow grass and with shy polite gray eyes, with a mouth that worked when he thought.” (Steinbeck, 4) -The Red Pony

Answer (score 2):

*Work* here is used in the general sense of *move* or *shape*. The boy is fidgeting with his mouth—biting or pursing his lips, or moving his tongue absentmindedly—while he thinks.

Comment: Or possibly silently mouthing the words he is thinking.